# Unable to stop service with IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, service, indexoutofboundsexception, exoplayer, foreground-service

my app are showing interesting crashes. I adde the 4 most common crash logs but I can't explain them. Has anyone encountered a similar problem? p.s I don't use `ArrayList` anywhere in my code.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop service workers.BackgroundPlayer@c853ae2: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1

Caused by java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
   at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:477)
   at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.popParentState(LifecycleRegistry.java:202)
   at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.backwardPass(LifecycleRegistry.java:317)
   at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.sync(LifecycleRegistry.java:334)
   at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.moveToState(LifecycleRegistry.java:145)
   at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.handleLifecycleEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:131)
   at androidx.lifecycle.ServiceLifecycleDispatcher$DispatchRunnable.run(ServiceLifecycleDispatcher.java:105)
   at androidx.lifecycle.ServiceLifecycleDispatcher.postDispatchRunnable(ServiceLifecycleDispatcher.java:45)
   at androidx.lifecycle.ServiceLifecycleDispatcher.onServicePreSuperOnDestroy(ServiceLifecycleDispatcher.java:81)
   at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleService.onDestroy(LifecycleService.java:70)
   at workers.BackgroundPlayer.onDestroy(streamPlayer.kt:385)

Fatal Exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=10; index=-1
   at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:486)
   at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.popParentState(LifecycleRegistry.java:202)
   at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.forwardPass(LifecycleRegistry.java:301)
   at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.sync(LifecycleRegistry.java:339)
   at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.moveToState(LifecycleRegistry.java:145)
   at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.handleLifecycleEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:131)
   at androidx.lifecycle.ServiceLifecycleDispatcher$DispatchRunnable.run(ServiceLifecycleDispatcher.java:105)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:761)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:941)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:831)

Fatal Exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=10; index=-1
   at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:468)
   at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.pushParentState(LifecycleRegistry.java:206)
   at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.forwardPass(LifecycleRegistry.java:299)
   at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.sync(LifecycleRegistry.java:339)
   at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.moveToState(LifecycleRegistry.java:145)
   at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.handleLifecycleEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:131)
   at androidx.lifecycle.ServiceLifecycleDispatcher$DispatchRunnable.run(ServiceLifecycleDispatcher.java:105)
```

The Service class:

```
class BackgroundPlayer : LifecycleService() {

override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)

    return START_NOT_STICKY
}

// Start service player

fun start() {
    Thread {
        run {
            settingsLastPlayed(station)

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) startForegroundService(Intent(this, BackgroundPlayer::class.java).apply { putExtra(station) })
            else                                                startService(Intent(this, BackgroundPlayer::class.java)          .apply { putExtra(station) })
        }
    }.start()
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    releasePlayer()
    cancelRecording()

    super.onDestroy()
}

private fun releasePlayer() {
    mediaSession             ?.release()
    mediaSessionConnector    ?.setPlayer(null)
    playerNotificationManager?.setPlayer(null)
    exoPlayer                ?.release()
}
```

}

Comment: When do you get those crashes? When you start the service? Also, if you are using a foreground service you should also display a notification to the user https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services#Foreground .      EDIT:   And also, do you really need a LifecycleService, try using a Service instead.

Comment: This is likely an error in the api implementation - found a few examples when googled.  It occurs when calling super.onDestroy - which is presumably the very last thing your code is trying to do on that event.  If this is the case only thing you could do is catch the exception on `super.destroy()` to customize error reporting and suppress the propagation of exception.  However, it may be dispatched internally to the looper which means you couldn't catch the exception - so nothing could be done in that case.

Comment: @Cata I get crashes on firebase crashlytics, there is no more informations ... when where why. This is all the information I have. I also show notification and yes I need LifecycleService because I use RX and I need unsubscribe observables etc.

Comment: @Andy I don't know if it will help me when I wrap super.destroy() with try catch

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you call all methods like

```java
Lifecycle.addObserver()
```

and

```java
Lifecycle.removeObserver()
```

in `MainThread`.
Check any place in your code where you call these methods.